# Candidates for holographic QFT of 4D Einstein gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, holographic-principle

If we are to believe that holographic principle holds over a wide number of dimensions, and gravitational theories, but specially, those that are relevant to our universe, then there must be some 3D QFT that is the dual description of our current 4D General relativity, over what it seems to be asymptotically flat de-Sitter spacetime.

> What QFT theories are candidates for being the holographic dual of
>   gravitational theory in *our* universe?

Comment: Relevant/potential duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30556/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting and challenging question. The holographic principle, as you mentioned, states that the description of a volume of space can be thought of as encoded on a lower-dimensional boundary to the region, such as a light-like boundary like a gravitational horizon⁴. This implies that there is a duality between a theory of gravity in a higher-dimensional spacetime and a quantum field theory (QFT) in a lower-dimensional spacetime, without gravity.

One of the most famous examples of this duality is the AdS/CFT correspondence, which relates a five-dimensional theory of gravity in anti–de Sitter space (AdS) to a four-dimensional conformal field theory (CFT) on the boundary of AdS¹². This correspondence has been extensively studied and tested in various contexts, such as black hole physics, quantum information theory, and condensed matter physics. However, it is not directly applicable to our universe, which is not anti–de Sitter, but rather de Sitter, or asymptotically flat.

Finding a holographic dual for de Sitter space or asymptotically flat space is much harder, because these spaces do not have a well-defined boundary or a clear notion of time. There are some proposals for such dualities, but they are not as well understood or established as the AdS/CFT correspondence. Some of these proposals are:

- The dS/CFT correspondence, which relates a four-dimensional theory of gravity in de Sitter space to a three-dimensional Euclidean CFT on the past or future boundary of de Sitter space. This correspondence is motivated by the analogy between the cosmological horizon of de Sitter space and the event horizon of a black hole, which can be described by a CFT according to the AdS/CFT correspondence. However, this correspondence faces some conceptual and technical difficulties, such as the lack of a unique vacuum state, the presence of infrared divergences, and the violation of unitarity and causality in the CFT.
- The flat space holography, which relates a four-dimensional theory of gravity in asymptotically flat space to a three-dimensional nonlocal theory on the celestial sphere at null infinity. This theory is inspired by the observation that the scattering amplitudes of massless particles in flat space can be mapped to correlation functions of a CFT on the celestial sphere, where the conformal dimension is related to the energy and the spin of the particles. However, this theory is not a full-fledged holographic dual, because it does not account for massive particles, gravity, or the bulk dynamics of flat space.
- The quantum error correction approach, which relates a four-dimensional theory of gravity in a generic spacetime to a quantum error correcting code on a lower-dimensional Hilbert space. This approach is based on the idea that the holographic principle is a manifestation of quantum entanglement, and that the bulk spacetime geometry can be reconstructed from the entanglement structure of the boundary quantum state. However, this approach does not specify a concrete model of the boundary theory or the code, and it does not address the issue of how to define observables and measurements in the bulk or the boundary.

These are some of the current attempts to find a holographic dual for gravitational theory in our universe, but none of them are conclusive or satisfactory. There may be other possibilities that have not been explored yet, or there may be some fundamental obstacle that prevents such a duality from existing. This is an open and active area of research in theoretical physics, and it may require new insights and breakthroughs to make further progress.

**My sources are listed below**

(1) Holographic principle - Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_principle.
(2) Is Our Universe a Hologram? Physicists Debate Famous Idea on Its 25th .... https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-our-universe-a-hologram-physicists-debate-famous-idea-on-its-25th-anniversary/.
(3) Is Our Universe a Hologram? Physicists Debate Famous Idea on Its 25th .... https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-our-universe-a-hologram-physicists-debate-famous-idea-on-its-25th-anniversary1/.
(4) A new take on holography - Inside The Perimeter. https://insidetheperimeter.ca/a-new-take-on-holography/.
(5) Could quantum gravity models arising from holography explain .... https://phys.org/news/2023-06-quantum-gravity-holography-cosmological.html.

Comment: thanks for the reply - De-Sitter has *a* cosmological horizon that is always increasing. Can you elaborate on the technical or conceptual reason this horizon cannot possibly work as a boundary? how is the non-uniqueness of vacuum a problem? is there a reason to believe there aren't some equivalence class of transformations that relates all of them up to some non-physical parameters?